# Now that the in-tree Kubernetes CephFS persistent volume plugin is deprecated how can I use Rook to get the same mounting behavior?

Tags: kubernetes, ceph, cephfs, rook

As of Kubernetes v1.28 the CephFS in-tree persistent volume plugin is [deprecated](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#cephfs). The official suggestion is to now instead use the third-party [CSI driver](https://github.com/ceph/ceph-csi). However, I am not sure how I can use for example, Rook, as a drop-in replacement for the original Kubernetes in-tree plugin.

The plugin has the ability to mount a ceph filesystem specified using the mon address, user, and secret. Mounting is also done to a local path and does not require specifying storage quotas.

Could someone give a simple example of how one can achieve the same or similar functionality as the original Kubernetes in-tree CephFS plugin using Rook and the Ceph CSI Driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with the Ceph CSI plugin using rook, I think the usage is different from the original in-tree Kubernetes plugin. In particular the way that the CSI plugin manages storage provisioning in the Ceph filesystem of choice is to create/delete subdirectories in the FS. In particular, the created persistent volume data is stored under `/volumes/csi/`. The full sub volume path can be found in the persistent volume's attributes but essentially the file system is partially (subpaths under `/volumes` at least) managed by the CSI driver.

Whereas before you would specify the subpath to mount into the container manually, with the CSI driver you would instead specify a volume name which would then refer to a specific subpath in the filesystem (created and managed by the CSI driver).

To share a volume/data across different containers, you would then need to reuse the same persistent volume name ([see the volumeName parameter of the PVC spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.24/#persistentvolumeclaimspec-v1-core)) and ensure that the persistent volume has a `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` of `Retain`. If your default policy is `Delete` you would need to edit the PV spec and change it to `Retain`.

This procedure is somewhat described in the Rook documentation in more detail [here](https://rook.io/docs/rook/v1.10/Storage-Configuration/Shared-Filesystem-CephFS/filesystem-storage/#shared-volume-creation). One thing to note is that it seems that you can't manually set the `volumeName` of a PV upon creation from a PVC. I'm not sure if you could also create a PV manually rather than through a PVC.

There could also be a more straightforward way to accomplish this that I'm not familiar with. The main purpose is to share data across multiple containers and the host itself (using `mount -t ceph`). The data would then be written from the host and read by containers.